# the quantum world: is $f$ balanced or constant?

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information, bit-strings

Why [here](https://www.fi.muni.cz/usr/gruska/quantum13f/qc1305.pdf) on the page 15, the fact whether $f$ is constant or balanced is derived from the value of $f$ at $0$ only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just $f(0)$, we should also take into account the text before the formulas, telling us that $(3)$ and $(4)$ are for the case of a constant $f$ while $(5)$ and $(6)$ are for a balanced $f$.

We can rewrite slide 15 as follows:

The final state is $\frac12 (-1)^{f(0)}(|0\rangle+(-1)^{f(0)\oplus f(1)}|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$ -- this is eq. $(2)$. (Well, not the ultimately final state, but the state right after applying $U_f$.)

Consider 4 possibilities for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ and substitute these values to eq. $(2)$:

1. $f$ is constant and $f(0)=0$, so $f(1)=0$; then eq. $(2)$ becomes eq. $(3)$, and the final state is $\frac12 (|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$;
2. $f$ is constant and $f(0)=1$, so $f(1)=1$; then eq. $(2)$ becomes eq. $(4)$, and the final state is $-\frac12 (|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$;
3. $f$ is balanced and $f(0)=0$, so $f(1)=1$; then eq. $(2)$ becomes eq. $(5)$, and the final state is $\frac12 (|0\rangle-|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$;
4. $f$ is balanced and $f(0)=1$, so $f(1)=0$; then eq. $(2)$ becomes eq. $(6)$, and the final state is $-\frac12 (|0\rangle-|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$.

Note that when we measure the 1st qubit, we don't learn anything about $f(0)$, however we can determine if $f$ is constant (the qubit is in the state $|0'\rangle$, cases $(3)$ and $(4)$) or balanced ($|1'\rangle$, cases $(5)$ and $(6)$).

Comment: I do not follow your argument, you say that $f(0)$ should read (means) $f(|0\rangle|0\rangle)$ ?

Comment: No... Now I don't follow your argument in the question: slides 14 and 15 contain not only $f(0)$ but also $f(1)$, don't they?

Comment: You are too quick for me. $(3),(4),(5)$ and $(6)$ look at the value at $0$ of $f$ only.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. It's not just $f(0)$, we should also take into account the text before the formulas, telling us that $(3)$ and $(4)$ are for the case of a constant $f$ while $(5)$ and $(6)$ are for a balanced $f$. Note that when we measure the 1st qubit, we don't learn anything about $f(0)$, however we can determine if $f$ is constant (the qubit is in the state $|0'\rangle$, cases $(3)$ and $(4)$) or balanced ($|1'\rangle$, cases $(5)$ and $(6)$).
I'll better include this into the answer.

Comment: I still do not follow how it follows that $(5)$,say, yields that $f$ is balanced. Let me rewrite this line $(5)$ here: $$\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)=|1'\rangle|1'\rangle\text{ if }f(0)=0.$$ Which part of this formula says/implies that $f$ is balanced ?? We should have either $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ of vice versa: $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ for $f$ to be balanced ! How $(5)$ implies this is the case ?

Comment: We do have either $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ in the case $(3)$ etc., but it's not an implication of $(3)$, it is its precondition. I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Though my question is not well received, I've learnt from your answer what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please specify whether these two states are orthogonal so that we can distinguish them by measuring : $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle-|1\rangle$ ? How can I prove that they are indeed orthogonal ?

Comment: Well, $(\langle0|+\langle1|)(|0\rangle-|1\rangle) = \langle0|0\rangle + \langle1|0\rangle-\langle0|1\rangle-\langle1|1\rangle $ $= 1+0-0-1 = 0$. Equivalently, the scalar product of the vectors (using the language of linear algebra) $(1, 1)$ and $(1, -1)$ is $0$.